# Ionic - opening new modal from modal

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, ionic-framework

I have default sidemeu template.

In the existing modal I`m trying to add another button:

```
<button class="button button-block button-small button-outline" ng-click="register()">Register</button>
```

But it closes opened modal and does nothing. In console I can see following message:

```
undefined Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

Comment: The idea is to overlap the first modal or close the first one before opening the second? Can you post your controller sample here too?

Comment: If you look at this other somple that I modified you see that it works fine http://plnkr.co/edit/qJ5yz2?p=preview